# Calling a class method instantiated by ajax call in wordpress

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, ajax

I have an ajax call in Wordpress that instantiate a class. I want to be able to call the class methods in other functions.

Here is the code to demonstrate.

Ajax call:

```
  kalimahJS(".a").click(function() {

        var data = {
            'action': 'list_items'
        };

        kalimahJS.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        })
    })
```

PHP class:

```
<?php
class Plugin
{
    var $itemsClass;

    public function __construct()
    {

        add_action('wp_ajax_list_items', array(
            $this,
            'list_items'
        ));
    }

    function list_items()
    {
        // Get class instance
        $this->itemsClass = new itemsClass();

        echo "success";
        die();
    }

    function another_function()
    {
        // Can't access this function
        $this->itemsClass->list_items();

        return false;
    }
}
```

I am not able to access `list_items()` method of `$this->itemsClass` since it is instantiated from an Ajax call. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Another way to do what? it is not very clear what are you actually trying to do

Answer (score 1):

You class method need to be `static` to be access without initializing the class or `public` in order to access from the class itself without reference `&`. And the variable `$this->itemsClass` also need to be public. So the workaround is -

```
class Plugin
{
    public $itemsClass;

    function __construct()
    {

        add_action('wp_ajax_list_items', array(
            $this,
            'list_items'
        ));
    }

    public function list_items()
    {
        // Get class instance
        self::$itemsClass = new itemsClass();

        echo "success";
        die();
    }

    public function another_function()
    {
        // Can't access this function
        self::$itemsClass->list_items();

        return false;
    }
}
```